# Should I use ec2 or lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I plan to deploy progressively multiple small sized aws instances for my app project. I read that AWS EC2 is limited to 20 instances per region and If I need more , I will need to make a request to increase the limit.

On the other hand, there are aws lightsail servers that seems more user-friendly but also less flexible. Does it offer a hourly-billed plan ? What about the 20 instances limitation per region ?

Anyway what would you suggest to me ?

Comment: Lightsail is priced monthly. It probably has a pro-rata rate, but your use-case sounds more appropriate to EC2.

Comment: If you're foreseeing a minimum number of active instances of the same instance type, consider opting for the reserved instances - could save you quite a penny in the long term

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the limits and billing?

Answer (score 3):

> What about the 20 instances limitation per region ?

There is no such limit anymore. The limits are based on [number of vCPUs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-on-demand-instances.html#ec2-on-demand-instances-limits). For example, now you can run over 1000 t2.micro instances in a single region.

> Does it offer a hourly-billed plan ?

You are billed per hour, but plans are monthly. From [faq](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/):

> Lightsail plans are billed on an **on-demand hourly rate, so you pay only for what you use**. For every Lightsail plan you use, we charge you the fixed hourly price, up to the maximum monthly plan cost.